# using state from a context provider within my useEffect dependency array causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, shopify

I am using the `shopify-buy` SDK, which allows me to retrieve the current cart of the user. I am trying to store that cart in my `CartProvider` which is then used in my `Cart` component. The problem is when I retrieve information from the cart it's acting a little slow so my component needs to be updated when the state changes, currently I have the following in my `getShopifyCart` function which is located in my `CartProvider`.

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

const getShopifyCart = () => {
    return client.checkout
      .fetch(currentVendor.cartId)
      .then((res) => {
        const lineItemsData = res.lineItems.map((item) => {
          return {
            title: item.title,
            quantity: item.quantity,
          }
        })
        setCartItems(lineItemsData)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
```

In my `Cart` component I have the following `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getShopifyCart()
  }, [cartItems])
```

But this causes an infinite loop, even though the `cartItems` state isn't changing.

Comment: Calling `getShopifyCart` sets the `cartItems` state. It will always be set with a new object, which triggers the effect, calling the function again. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state `cartItems` inside `getShopifyCart` which you are calling inside a `useEffect` which has `cartItems` as a dependency. Even though the content of the data  has not changed, you are creating a new object, hence its hash has changed as well which causes the `useEffect` to be called again.

If you want to initially fetch the data and set the state, then you need to pass an empty dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   getShopifyCart()
}, [])
```